# Unable establish connection.Showing handshake error

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I get this error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.fixer.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest?base=INR (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure')))
```

upon running this code

```
response=requests.get("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base="+cfrm)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed too.

Comment: if you are using a free pythonanywhere account and that api.fixer.io site is not on the pythonanywhere whitelist, then you won't be able to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are getting "Max retries exceeded with url" errors, what is happening is the host is refusing the connection because you're quickly sending a lot of requests from the same IP address.

I'd need to see more code to know more, but I am guessing that you are calling requests.get too frequently, and need to put some time sleeps between your calls as to not spam the server.

Edit:
I see that the handshake is failing. This means you're having problems connecting and doing it frequently so you're being refused by the host.

Comment: def converter(request):
 if request.method=='POST':
  form=Converter(request.POST)
  cfrm = request.POST.get('convert_from')
  cto = request.POST.get('convert_to')
  amt = (request.POST.get('amount'))
  response=requests.get("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base="+cfrm)
  text=ast.literal_eval(response.text)
  rates=text['rates']
  amount =(rates[cto])*(float(amt))

  DATA="THE AMOUNT IS="+str(amount)

 else:
  DATA="Please Select The exchange rates"
  form = Converter()
        return render(request,'marksheet/converter.html',{"print":DATA,"form":form})